# Big O and T(n) Confusion

Tags: c++, for-loop, big-o

I'm currently am doing some homework about Big O and T(n) and have come across a couple issues. I have plugged in numbers like my professor said and have come up with how many times each loop is ran, but I can't figure out how to derive the T(n) and Big O from that information. I've looked throughout the site but can't seem to find any help. These are a couple problems that weren't assigned but are very similar to the assigned problems i am struggling with.

If you could work out step by step how to go about finding Big O and T(n) that'd be extremely help. Thanks for your time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 for (int j = 0; j < i * i; j++)
 cout << j << endl;

i=1 runs 1 time
i=2 runs 4 times
i=3 runs 9 times
i=4 runs 16 times

for (int i = n; i >= 0; i -= 2)
 cout << i << endl;

n=10 runs 6 times
n=8 runs 5 times
n=6 runs 4 times
n=4 runs 3 times
n=2 runs 2 times

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 for (int j = i; j > 0; j /= 2)
 cout << j << endl; 

i=16 runs 5 times
i=8 runs 4 times
i=4 runs 3 times
i=2 runs 2 times
```

Comment: Do you mean `Theta(n)`?

Comment: @Barmar Most probably not. `T(n)` means time to execute algorithm on problem of size `n`. It's a notation often used to describe recursive algorithms. E.g. `T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + c` means you can solve problem for `n` by splitting it into two problems half in size plus some constant time, for example calculating the middle or something. It is used to obtain `O` of the algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 1):

These are all very straightforward cases that all you have to do is count the number of iterations.

Let's take the first one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 for (int j = 0; j < i * i; j++)
   cout << j << endl;
```

For a specific value of `i`, we do `i^2` iterations of the inner loop. Thus, the total number of iterations of the inner most step is:

```
0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + ... + (n-1)^2
= (n-1)(n)(2n-1)/6  // it helps to just know the formula for sums of squares
= Ө(n^3)            // just drop all the constants
```

Just follow the same approach for the other two. The second one is trivial (`Ө(n)`), though the third is slightly more interesting (`O(n lg n)`).